# How can I enable replication in snowflake database using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform0.12+, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**How can I enable replication in snowflake database using terraform ?**

I am using chanzuckerberg snowfalke provider in terraform and was able to create the DB/SCHEMA/Warehouse/Tables/shares but I am not able to find the option to enable the database replication through terraform.

or Is there a way to enable run alter command on snowflake DB to enable the replication using terraform.

like :- alter database ${var.var_database_name} enable replication to accounts ${var.var_account_name};

Answer (score 0):

You first have to enable replication for your organization. There are two ways to do this. One option is to open a case with Snowflake Support. Another option is to use the Organizations feature. If you do not have the Organization feature enabled, you will need to open a case with Support to enable it. If you do have the Organizations feature, you will have at least one person in your organization who has the ORGADMIN role.

That person will need to follow these steps: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/database-replication-config.html#prerequisite-enable-replication-for-your-accounts

Once the accounts are enabled for replication, you can use SQL statements (orchestrated from Terraform or elsewhere) to promote a local database to the primary in a replication group: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/database-replication-config.html#promoting-a-local-database

After you then get secondary databases, you can run a single line of SQL on the secondary DB's account to initiate replication: `alter database <DB_NAME> refresh;`

Comment: Thanks for the update.. The replication is enabled on snowflake level. I want to execute "alter database ${var.var_database_name} enable replication to accounts ${var.var_account_name};" command to enable the DB replication using snowflake terraform provider. Is there any way out through Terraform. If yes, can you please share the example. 

Thanks.